# how do i set value of a textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript, textbox, setvalue

I am trying to get a value fro query string and assign that value into a textbox.
I am able to get the value from query string but unable to assign it to textbox.

```
document.getElementByName('Contact0Email').Value = email;
```

Tried the above code but doesn't seem to be working. Though the alert of email gives the right value.

Comment: If you're just beginning with javascript, I suggest you take a look at the f-a-n-t-a-s-t-i-c jQuery library - jquery.com. In jquery you'd do the following: `$("#Contact0Email").val(email);`

Comment: Also, I think you'd have better luck with [getElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) instead of [getElementsByName](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp) (note the 's' in Elements)

Comment: @yuval: I'd argue that it's better to get an appreciation of the DOM API first. Then use one of the many libraries available if you want. Knowing the DOM API helps prevent library abuse.

Comment: @yuval, you're not going to load a 26 KB library just to save 26 characters.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need a lower-case `value` and a plural `Elements`:

```
document.getElementsByName('Contact0Email')[0].value = email;
```

You need the `[0]` to get the first element in the list.  Names don't have to be unique like ids.